# OpenCV & Python - How does one filter noise from an irregular shaped polygon detected by OpenCV using a Kalman filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, kalman-filter

I have a small tracking project that I am working on. I have my frame by frame detection scheme setup and working. When I run I get a fair amount of noise in the polygon that I extract even if the scene is static. Since I want this run in real time, it seems Kalman filtering is the best way to solve this problem; however implementation details are sparse. I have seen some examples via google, but they typically deal with bounding boxes or regular shapes, which are described with only a few bits of info. I am not sure that approach would work.

I am interested in tracking the evolution of a more irregular geometry below. It takes ~100 points or more to describe the polygon. How can I adapt the OpenCV kalman tools to handle this task?

Thanks in advance.

** **Update** **

So additional details. I need to have an accurate profile of the object for downstream analysis so a bounding box is not an option. My camera can produce frames at 30 fps, but I do not need to process that fast, though I do not want to only process 1 a second either. Doing a fast de-noising operation is too slow. My images are 4024x3036 monochrome images. I attached jpeg versions of six shots of my scene. The sample is the small chunk in the center of the two plates in the bottom third of the image. I also attached what I am looking to pull from each frame an irregular polygon that matches the 2d profile of the shape accurately. I will favor accuracy and stability over speed but I would like to process a few frames per second.

I will go capture some representative images or small movie and will post shortly.

Thanks in advance.

Sample Images

[image: Shot 1]

[image: Shot 2]

[image: Shot 3]

[image: Shot 4]

[image: Shot 5]

[image: Shot 6]

The goal

[image: Example of what I am looking for]

Comment: to reduce the noise you are technically trying to smooth/filter the points. kalman or OneEuro filter require a fixed number of points and they have to always be presented in the same order so idk if kalman on a changing polygon will help. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do or why so I cant suggest any alternatives

Comment: @Ta946 Hmm the same order of points would be difficult. The contour I am tracking will deform has the top and bottom squish the object in the middle. So I have a rough idea of what the shape will be based on my current frame and I would like for the measurement to be less jumpy. I tried taking noise out of the entire frame but that slows down processing quite a bit. It helps somewhat but I still get some movement. I read that tracking is more efficient but it only works with bounding boxes. I guess this is why.

Comment: Please post some sample original frames for us to work with, thanks.

Comment: @AnnZen I updated the post with more details and a few images.

Comment: So basically, you want to find the contours of the polygon without much noise, keep the points in order and maintain the same number of points?

Comment: @AnnZen I do not need the number of points be the same but if that makes tracking the polygon accurately and with minimal noise than that is fine. I tried de-noising the image and that was too slow and  as far as I am aware the Kalman filter only works with individual points. I think this is a good question because people may interested in tracking more than a bounding box on occasion.

Comment: I see, I'll post a an answer soon. By the way, not that it matters, but I'm not too sure what is in the picture... is it a windshield or something?

Comment: Finally, will the camera/object move a lot, or are the images you provided enough to demonstrate how much variance to expect?

Comment: @AnnZen the camera is is stationary and the only things that will move are the two plates and the sample deforming between them.  The plate could come closer together creating a really thin sample or the top plate could separate from the sample and there would be a small gap on top. That is all that will ever happen in the scene.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice Okay, I've provided an answer. Feel free to address any points that I might've missed so that I can improve it.

Comment: @AnnZen Great, I am gonna try this out and will get back to you thanks for the effort thus far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Concept

Notice how among the columns of the images, the columns where the purple lines should go have the most black? We can detect the ROI *(region of interest)* by first detecting the first and last columns with at least certain amount of black. Then detect the rows between the 2 detected columns where the white color first starts and first ends at the 2 columns.

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

files = [f"img{i}.jpg" for i in range(1, 6)]

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    sum_cols = thresh.sum(0)
    indices = np.where(sum_cols < sum_cols.min() + 40000)[0]
    x1, x2 = indices[0] - 50, indices[-1] + 50
    diff1, diff2 = np.diff(thresh[:, [x1, x2]].T, 1)
    y1_1, y2_1 = np.where(diff1)[0][:2]
    y1_2, y2_2 = np.where(diff2)[0][:2]
    y1, y2 = min(y1_1, y1_2), max(y2_1, y2_2)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(thresh[y1: y2, x1: x2], 50, 50)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1_1), (x2, y1_2), (255, 0, 160), 5)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y2_1), (x2, y2_2), (255, 0, 160), 5)
    cv2.drawContours(img[y1: y2, x1: x2], contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 10)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

#### The Output

Here are what the program will output for each different image you provided:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### The Explanation

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Since you have a camera, obviously you're going to use the `cv2.VideoCapture()` method. As I only have the images you provided, I'll make the program read in each image. So, store every image filename into a list *(I have `img1.jpg`, `img1.jpg`, ... `img5.jpg`)*, iterate through the names and read in each image:

```
files = [f"img{i}.jpg" for i in range(1, 6)]

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
```

3. Convert each image into grayscale, and use the `cv2.threshold()` method to convert the grayscale images to have only 2 values; `0` for each pixel that's less or equal to `127`, and `255` for each pixel that's more than `127`:

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

4. In order to find the columns with the most `0`s *(which means with most black)*, we'll need to find the sum of every column, where the smallest sum will be from the column with the most `0`s. With the sum of each column, we can use the `np.where()` method to find the index of every column in the thresholded image that sums up to a number close to the smallest sum detected. Then, we can get the first index and the last index of the detected columns to be the `x1` and `x2` of our ROI *(along with a padding of `50` pixels)*:

```
    sum_cols = thresh.sum(0)
    indices = np.where(sum_cols < sum_cols.min() + 40000)[0]
    x1, x2 = indices[0] - 50, indices[-1] + 50
```

5. In order to find the `y1` and `y2` of the top lines, we'll need to detect the index of the first occurrence of a change from `0` to `255` in the first edge of the detected columns and in the last edge of the detected columns. Similarly, in order to find the `y1` and `y2` of the bottom line, we'll need to detect the index of the first occurrence of a change from `255` to `0` in the first edge of the detected columns and in the last edge of the detected columns. Finally, with our 4 `y` coordinates, we can get the `y1` and `y2` of our ROI by getting the smallest of the `y` coordinates in the first line, and the greatest of the `y` coordinates in the second line:

```
    diff1, diff2 = np.diff(thresh[:, [x1, x2]].T, 1)
    y1_1, y2_1 = np.where(diff1)[0][:2]
    y1_2, y2_2 = np.where(diff2)[0][:2]
    y1, y2 = min(y1_1, y1_2), max(y2_1, y2_2)
```

6. Now we have our ROI. We can detect the edges of the objects within out ROI using the Canny edge detector, and detect the contours of the edges using the `cv2.findContours()` method:

```
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(thresh[y1: y2, x1: x2], 50, 50)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

7. Finally, we can draw on the lines and the contours onto the non-binary images, and show the images:

```
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1_1), (x2, y1_2), (255, 0, 160), 5)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y2_1), (x2, y2_2), (255, 0, 160), 5)
    cv2.drawContours(img[y1: y2, x1: x2], contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 10)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: This is beautiful, my code was had about 6 times the lines but was slow and noisy. I greatly appreciate you breaking down your code line by line. A couple questions before I close this out. 1) Is your approach of looking at col or row values the fastest way to identify images? My code repeatedly looked for contours and I assume is not the best way to do it 2) Why did you use the Canny edge detection before the contour step? I worry because Canny has never worked for me before but it seems to fine but it would be nice to know why it works here. 3) How did you come up with the Canny parameters?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice My pleasure. Addressing your questions: 1) If I knew a faster way I would've posted it, so as far as I know, yes. 2) Using the Canny edge detector before detecting the contours greatly reduces noise. 3) It's sort of instinctive for me, but whenever I need to fine-tone the values, I use cv2 trackbars, which allows interactive values adjusting. Here is an example script: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhKgT.png and what it does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUoJk.gif.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution and see if the contours are still jumpy and let Mr. Kalman rest in peace :) The following code will only produce contours partly belonging to your object and partly to the upper and lower side of the plates. You will have to do a little more processing to join two lines to get the whole object contours. Assumption in the code is that the sub-image will alway contain the ROI. Btw., I highly doubt that you can use Kalman here as you do not have fixed trackable/identifiable contour points. Processing speed should be fairly efficient so as to allow you multiple images per second.

```
gw1,gs1,gw2,gs2 = (5,1,7,3)

rgb = cv2.imread('/your/test/image/so_kalman.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
wk_img = gray[2000:2500, 500:2000] # Work on a sub-image
min_ctr_area = 30000
max_ctr_area = 70000

g1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(wk_img, (gw1, gw1), gs1)
g2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(wk_img, (gw2, gw2), gs2)
ret, th = cv2.threshold(g2-g1, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

h, w = th.shape
cv2.rectangle(th, (0, 0), (w, h), 255, 5)

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(th.copy(),cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
out_img = rgb[2000:2500, 500:2000].copy()

for i in range(len(contours)):
    if hier[0][i][3] == -1:
        continue

    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
    if min_ctr_area < w*h < max_ctr_area:
        cv2.drawContours(out_img, [contours[i]], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)

plt.imshow(out_img)
```

Here is a [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwJr2.jpg) on one of your test images. This is a simple solution but hopefully should work to your expectations.